# Is there a shorter syntax to insert values into a postgres table using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert many columns into a table row using psycopg2 with Python 2.7. Is there a way for me to shorten the INSERT syntax? I currently have to type out the placeholder (%s) over and over again like VALUES(%s,%s,%s,...%s)

Edit:
Currently I have

```
tableCursor.execute('INSERT INTO "table" ("x1","x2","x3","x4")' +
            'VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)', (val1,val2,val3,val4))
```

I want to use more than placeholders but it's kinda repetitive to keep typing %s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

If you have enough columns that this is an issue, then (a) you probably need to re-think your schema design, and (b) you can always use `', '.join(['%s']*n)` where `n` is the number of parameters to produce the string.

```
>>> ', '.join(['%s']*7)
'%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s'

>>> 'INSERT INTO tablename(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7) VALUES (' + ', '.join(['%s']*7) + ');'
'INSERT INTO tablename(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);'
```

I agree that it'd be nice to have `psycopg` automatically deduce the `VALUES` list based on the number of columns named if you didn't give it one explicitly. It doesn't, though, and it's easy enough to DIY.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
tableCursor.execute('INSERT INTO "table" ("x1","x2","x3","x4")' +
            'VALUES %s', [(val1,val2,val3,val4)])
```

Tuples are adapted by recursively adapt their arguments and put in parentheses, so they are good to represent records, composite types or lists of values for IN.